# Can anybody please confirm why an error is being returned in Python 2.6 for the following? Is this for 3.0 Syntax?

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
# Get the user's first name.
first_name = input('Enter your first name: ')

# Get the user's last name.
last_name = input('Enter your last name: ')

# Print a greeting to the user.
print('Hello', first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: It is Python 3 syntax.

Comment: sort of ... input is valid in python 2.x (even if its a bad idea...) also calling print like a  function works fine in 2x... but yeah its obviously targetted to 3x

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That `print` statement is printing a tuple then, which is also not what was intended.

Comment: no its not ... not unless you try an string together strings with comma's (like he is doing :P)

Answer (score 3):

Use `raw_input` and a `print` *statement*:

```
# Get the user's first name.
first_name = raw_input('Enter your first name: ')

# Get the user's last name.
last_name = raw_input('Enter your last name: ')

# Print a greeting to the user.
print 'Hello', first_name, last_name
```

Python 3 renamed the old `raw_input` function to `input`; in Python 2, `input()` is means the same thing as `eval(raw_input())` instead, which will attempt to interpret the input given as a Python expression.

You may want to install Python 3 instead or consider switching tutorials.

Comment: meh `print(whatever)` works fine in 2x .... but convention tells us to use statement ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Using commas in the `whatever` expression means it'll print a *tuple* instead of concatenating the values with spaces between. That is a *big* difference. You also cannot do `print(whatever,)` and expect to not get a newline printed.

Answer (score 1):

use `raw_input` instead ... `input` attempts to evaluate whatever it gets in python 2.x